# Phonegap Filetransfer download

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, file-transfer

I'm new on stackoverflow. it's the first time that I have to use Phonegap and really I have a problem. I need to make a table and by clicking on each element starts to download a pdf file and create a new folder (if it does not exist).  But I can not even download a file after compiling with phonegap. All the examples I saw, just download an image through onload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadFile(){
 var url = 'http://http://legalespymes.com.ar/legalespymes/abonos/aseguradoras.pdf';
    var filePath = 'local/path/to/your/file';
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(url);
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        filePath,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        false,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<td onclick="downloadFile()">Row 1</td>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you have the FileTransfer plugin enabled and the correct package name specified in your config.xml?

Comment: did the 'deviceready' event fired before trying to do that?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124217/cordova-filetransfer-download-error/24124917#24124917

Answer (score 0):

First of all your url is invalid included http multiple times

```
var url = 'http://http://legalespymes.com.ar/legalespymes/abonos/aseguradoras.pdf';
```

change like this

```
var url = 'http://legalespymes.com.ar/legalespymes/abonos/aseguradoras.pdf';
```

If you are create multiple directory and store file inside that directory this may be create issue.(example [project/sample/local] not created same time. so file not download).And make sure file download plugins are available in config.xml and specify phonegap version.

Use this code to create multiple directory at time.

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

// create directory
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    window.FS = fileSystem;
    var printDirPath = function(entry){
        console.log("Dir path - " + entry.fullPath);
    }

    createDirectory("local/path/to/your", printDirPath);
}
function fail() {
    console.log("failed to get filesystem");
}

function createDirectory(path, success){
    var dirs = path.split("/").reverse();
    var root = window.FS.root;
    var createDir = function(dir){
        console.log("create dir " + dir);
        root.getDirectory(dir, {
            create : true,
            exclusive : false
        }, successCB, failCB);
    };

    var successCB = function(entry){
        root = entry;
        if(dirs.length > 0){
            createDir(dirs.pop());
        }else{
            success(entry);
        }
    };

    var failCB = function(){
    };

    createDir(dirs.pop());
}
```

Now you write your file download code .